# Taking screenshots from random frames of a video file

Tags: command-line, screenshot, mp4, capture

How can I take sequential screenshots from a video file using **terminal**?
With `ffmpeg` I could capture a single frame, but I need something like this
[image]

Comment: OK, is your idea to mount a multiframed picture, using a looping = for(x; for(y; catch; put(x,y))) x lines y columns...?

Comment: Related:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63769/fast-tool-to-generate-thumbnail-video-galleries-for-command-line

Comment: @Terrance I think that's what OP's looking for. Could you please add an answer with the *Unix & Linux* link as a reference?

Answer (score 1):

It's a GUI solution, but a very simple one. You may use **SMPlayer** for this purpose.

1. Open a video with SMPlayer and select **Menu > Video > Thumbnail Generator**.
   [image]
2. You should get a few options to play with.
   [image]
3. Select *OK* and you'll get the final output.
   [image]

Since SMPlayer is a front-end for `mplayer`, I believe same can be achieved using Terminal with the proper usage of `mplayer` command.

[Video source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Nieuws_uit_Indonesi%C3%AB,_autodumps_in_Batavia,_Nederlandse_Rode_Kruis_hulp_in_Pangkalpinang,_tinbewerking_op_Bangka_Weeknummer_46-45_-_Open_Beelden_-_16864.ogv)

Comment: Provide that mplayer command?